# Vuejs - how to correctly logout the user?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good evening,

I'm using Laravel with VueJS and I have a little problem with disconnection.

Example: I open 2 tabs, log out on one, go back to the other, and I can still do what I want, like create a user.
But I can't change route (that's normal, I use a befor each in the router).

How can I do that, to prevent any action being in the same route?

Thank you in advance, don't hesitate to ask me more info if you need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Server-side

You need to check for the non-expiration of the session:

```
if(Auth::check()) { 
    // Code which should only run if the user has a valid session
} else {
    // Code for handling the non-existence of session
}
```

## Client-side

Your client-side should always know if a request has succeeded and handle eventual failures. This is valid for a session which expired for some reason, but other issues as well, like request timeout, or even some errors.

## Make sure the logout happened

Something like this

```
Auth::logout();
```

should be executed when you log out.

Comment: I'm really stupid, I handled the disconnection only on the front side, with the removal of the token, but I forgot to do the Auth()->logout()...
Thanks anyway for your precious help!